# Differences between "now", "present", "recent" and "current"

Tags: meaning, differences

When writting a resume, we may put the duration of our current job like this:

> 2012 to **Present** --------- Job ---------Company

How about using *now* instead in this case?

And when used as adjectives, what are the differences between them? (except for *now*, which is not an adjective)

Comment: Rephrase the question, something like "why *present*, why not *now* in this expression?" and post it on ELL -- not here. All the best.

Comment: I'm not down voting or voting to close. May be suitable for ELL.

Comment: "Now" used as an adjective? We'd need an example.

Comment: @Kris What's ELL?     Got it.

Comment: should I just delete this question or is there a way to move it to ELL?

Answer (score -1):

I usually word it as: 2012  - current, which means it's still in the present time.

Comment: -1 Why? Anything in support?

Comment: Using a hyphen like that is wrong.

Comment: then how about using ~ instead? (don't know how to call this symbol)

Comment: One uses en dashes (–) to separate ranges.